# In Github, how do I rollback upstream branch back to the commit to which my origin branch is currently pointing?

Tags: git, github

We are using Git Forking Workflow. The upstream branch is ahead of my origin branch by n commits. How do I set it back to the commit to which my origin branch is currently pointing?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Is your intention to get rid of those n commits which are sitting on the remote branch?  Also, is your branch shared by anyone besides yourself?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, please check my comment to Luke's answer. I have explained it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question right you are wanting to make the remote branch match your local branch by removing the n number of commits that it is ahead by.

To do this you can simply force a push to the remote repo with the following:

```
git push -f <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

You should be very careful doing this though. Double check with everyone else in your team that they want you to do this.

Comment: actually both the branches are remote. One is upstream which is common for all devs (although I am the only one working currently) and other is my remote origin. Upstream is ahead of origin by n commits. Generally the origin is ahead in which case, I create a PR from origin to upstream and then accept merge at upstream. But, in this case, I don't know how to proceed ?

Comment: Should you even be proceeding at all if `origin` be behind `upstream` ?